# Ruby library to monitor system resources

Tags: ruby, rubygems, monitoring

Do you know a library to access system resources for Ruby? I would like to monitor CPU, disk, RAM, network...

It would be great to have a library to monitor not only Linux, but even FreeBSD, Windows, Solaris and Mac.

Comment: I have found this: http://rubyforge.org/projects/sysutils/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sysutils` is quite good, but CHEF has created [Ohai](https://github.com/opscode/ohai). Ohai is used by Chef and it is very comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

[Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) is the one that I use.  Very simple configuration (not Ruby), lots of samples on the web, etc.  I'm biased towards this one because I've used it the most.

Another popular one is [god](http://god.rubyforge.org/).  Unlike Monit it uses Ruby as the configuration language.  I've never used god, but I've heard both good and bad about it.  The worst being that it slowly sucks up memory.  This isn't god per se, but the Ruby interpreter that you run under.  Just something to keep in mind.

**edit** Neither of these work on Windows.  I've had good luck with Monit on Linux (Ubuntu, OpenSUSE, and Fedora builds - all 2.6 kernels), Mac OS X 10.5 (never tried older), and NetBSD.

Comment: I've used both of these, but they're applications and as far as I know they don't include a library or expose an API to enable you to write your own wrapper around them.

Comment: Monit definitely isn't a library.  But looking through god's sources, it is nicely factored out.  I don't think it would be a huge problem to just use the pieces you were interested in.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good library you can use:
http://rubyforge.org/projects/sysutils

Answer (score 1):

I too searched for a simple and good library to do that...

I came across

> Usagewatch

and after 5 minutes had my monitoring.rb done..

Install : `gem install usagewatch`

Install on mac : `gem install usagewatch_ext`

Refer to [this](http://www.philchen.com/2013/07/17/linux-usage-statistics-using-ruby-gem-usagewatch) article for more info